# How do I list my inbox from my Gmail account into a spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script

**GOAL:** I would like to know if there is any apps script code for listing all the inbox details of your current gmail account to a spreadsheet.
Currently after reading through all the possible functions and methods about Gmail in Apps Script, I have not found any way according to my knowledge as of how to gain this. 
The link I am talking about is here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail

Answer (score 0):

### For example:

You can use the [`GmailApp.getInboxThreads()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#getinboxthreads) to get the messages, and then SpreadsheetApp's [`Range.setValue(value)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue) to set the value in a cell.

Of course you have to program your own logic into it. So share your code ;).